# Combining TikZ foreach and let operation

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm not having any luck using the TikZ `let` operation inside a `foreach` loop. Is there anything I'm missing?

Sample code (that doesn't work):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \y in {1,2,3}
     {\draw (0,0) -- (3,\y);
      \draw let 
        \p1 = (3,\y),
        \n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)} in
      (\y,0) arc [start angle = 0, end angle = \n1, radius=\y];
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `let` synax is perfectly valid inside a `\foreach`. You do however have a clash of variable names: The `\y` from the loop conflicts with the `\y⟨n⟩` from `let`. Simply renaming the loop counter solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a in {1,2,3}
     {\draw (0,0) -- (3,\a);
      \draw let 
        \p1 = (3,\a),
        \n1 = {atan2(\x1,\y1)} in
      (\a,0) arc [start angle = 0, end angle = \n1, radius=\a];
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The underlying problem is that TeX macro names cannot contain numbers. So `let` has to define a macro called `\y` that reads the `1` (or other number) as a parameter and then redirects to the correct value. This of course overrides the `\y` coming from the loop. So you (presumably) get an error on `(\y,0)`, because the new `\y` (inside the `let`) expects to be followed by a number, not a `,`.

Comment: This also made me suffer! This incompatibility should be mentioned in TikZ manual.